# Innerclasses marked as without sharing/Outerclass is with sharing

Tags: apex, sharing

I had this use case where i need to run the entire class in 'respecting sharing rules of org'

But in there i had to  query Entitysubscirption object

```
list<EntitySubscription>listt = [Select c.SubscriberId ,c.parentid From EntitySubscription  c where c.parentid in :Allremaningids and c.subscriberId = :UserInfo.getUserId()  ];
```

This will give me below error when run as a non-admin user.

```
Implementation restriction: EntitySubscription only allows security evaluation for non-admin users when LIMIT is specified and at most 1000
```

Now how i dealt with this,

1. I marked the whole class as without sharing. This works because as its obvious,it runs as system admin.But disadvantage was i had to write explicit queries to enforce sharing and maintenance in future is going to be difficult ,if sharing changes.
2. I marked all the class as with sharing.
   I declared an inner class without sharing,executed the query there .
   Then i  create object in outerclass,call 
   list listt = obj.method(Id id);
   This works as i think innerclass is being run in without sharing and other class respects sharing.

**Now i dont really know whether there is any other disadvantage for this approach?like limits etc?Anyone any idea?**

Comment: I believe apex classes are run in the sharing mode of the calling class, are you sure you've tested this correctly ?

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm                                                             'The sharing setting of the class where the method is defined is applied, not of the class where the method is called. For example, if a method is defined in a class declared with with sharing is called by a class declared with without sharing, the method will execute with sharing rules enforced.'

Comment: I thought above suggests--its the class where method is defined?

Comment: Did my answer suffice for this question? Or was there something missing in the answer?

Answer (score 4):

I have done this before actually.

What I did was created a seperate class that needed the funtionality without the sharing rules. Then I used that class to carry out my functionality.

For example:

```
 public with sharing class ClassNeedingSharing
 {
     public void MethodWithSomeFunctionality()
     {
        NoSharingClass ExampleTwo = new NoSharingClass();
        ExampleTwo.FunctionWithoutSharing();
        NoSharingClass.StaticFunctionWithoutSharing();
     }
 }
```

Then in the opposing class:

```
public without sharing class NoSharingClass
{
   public void FunctionWithoutSharing()
   {
      //Logic needed without security or access permissions
   }

   public static void StaticFunctionWithoutSharing()
   {
     //Static method without sharing
   }
}
```

The article you mentioned further verifies that statement.

I approve that approach because in times where you **do** need sharing rules or not, you have an easy way of choosing so.

As far as limit concerns and what-not, I don't believe so (you may have more records with `without sharing` is the only one I can think of). Honestly, I cannot see a disadvantage of properly structuring your code based on sharing inheritance because it would make a lot of sense in this situation. Just as long as you are careful with the functionality of anything within the `without sharing` class.